# Is there a name for relations where the domain and range are the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

The title says it all: is there a special name for relations $R$ where $$\operatorname{dom}(R) = \operatorname{ran}(R)$$

...?

In case the definitions of $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(R)$ are not standardized, this is what I mean by them:
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{dom}(R) = \{x: \exists y \;\;\mathrm{such\;that}\;\; xRy \} \\
\operatorname{ran}(R) = \{y: \exists x \;\;\mathrm{such\;that}\;\; xRy \}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I know that when $R$ is defined as some subset of $A \times A$ (i.e. when the left and right elements are pulled lit of the same set $A$, then $R$ is an *endo-relation* … but I don’t think that’s what you’re looking for, right?

Comment: @Bram28: Thanks, but no, not really.  I think the condition I'm looking for is stronger.

Comment: Yeah, I figured ... you could have $R$ be an endo-relation on $A$, have both $dom(R)$ and $ran(R)$ be strict subsets of $A$, and have $dom(R) = ran(R)$. Well, interesting idea, but I've never heard any term for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of, in a bit of a janky way.

Suppose $R$ is a relation on $X$ (i.e. $R \subseteq X \times X$).

- Suppose further that $X = \text{dom}(R)$. (Hence, each $x \in X$ satisfies $(x,y) \in R$ for some $y \in X$.) Then we say that $R$ is "(left-)total" or "serial". ([Wikipedia link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_relation))
- $R$ may be called "surjective" (or "onto" or "right-total") if $X = \text{ran}(R)$ (independent of the previous condition), i.e. that $\forall y \in X$ there is an $x \in X$ such that $(x,y) \in R$. ([Brief Wikipedia blurb.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#:%7E:text=%3D%20x.-,Surjective,-(also%20called%20right)))

(A third [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) that frames things more explicitly in terms of domain/range.)

Hence, any combination of those terms would be an applicable name to a relation $R$ on $X$ where $\text{dom}(R) = \text{ran}(R) = X$, e.g. you may call it "left- and right-total."